# Change from Eclipse to Android studio and vise-versa without driving VCS crazy

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, android-studio

I have an assignment to do for my university. We have to build an android app using eclipse and using SVN as VCS.

My teacher strictly demanded Eclipse. The problem is I want to use Android Studio for my app. I do not like to be restrained. Now, the only solutions I can think of are:

1. Have two separate projects. Eclipse project on svn directory and Android Studio somewhere else and every time I want to commit I just update Eclipse project by hand.
2. Have both projects on the same directory and try to configure my svn:ignore to avoid completely android studio.

The 2nd solution seems way more elegant than the 1st one but I do not know if it is possible. Even if it is, it doesn't exactly solve the problem. For example, if I add a new file to Android Studio, it will not be automatically added in Eclipse as well.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish the second solution or even better, suggest a better way to solve the problem?

**Tldr**: I want to have Android Studio project but when I push on remote repository I want to appear as Eclipse project. And all that without doing everything by hand.

**Note**: If you look the accepted answer, check out the comments as well. They are helpful.

**Note 2**: [This link](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/Make-Android-Eclipse-project-ready-for-Android-Studio) was very helpful as well.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? You can specify any individual file or directory if needed in `svn:ignore`. Just get a list of files used by android studio and throw it into the property.

Comment: Even if that's the case, how to eclipse project files get updated from Android Studio?? For example, I add a new file to Android Studio. It will not be automatically add in Eclipse...

Comment: Right. You'll need to actually create a project and keep it up to date for Eclipse, it won't happen automatically. Just make it part of your turn-in procedure to update that project and make sure it still works, I guess, just like if your prof insisted on putting all files into an uncompressed .tar and uploading to a special drop-box, or printing out your source code and handing it in, or something like that.

Comment: Guess I was wrong about it not being automatic. Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean? Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Just saw the answer is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. Assuming you don't want to use an IDE-independent build system like Gradle or Maven, you can simply [link your Eclipse project with Android studio](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html):

> Q: How do I open my Eclipse projects now?
>
> A: Very simple. You have an option to either import, or link them.
> IntelliJ IDEA supports Eclipse classpath module dependencies, so you can link your Eclipse projects to IntelliJ IDEA and work even in a mixed IDE team. Alternatively, you can import an Eclipse project to IntelliJ IDEA native format if you don't need any backward compatibility.

You need to create an Eclipse project first, and then you import it into Android Studio: `File > Import project`. Check `Link created IntelliJ IDEA modules to Eclipse project files` and you're done. This will make it possible, to open the same project with both Android Studio and Eclipse. It will not only update your files, it will update some settings (like classpath) too. A step-by-step guide can be found on the [web help](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Importing+a+Project+from+Eclipse).

Comment: There isn't a "Link created IntelliJ IDEA modules to Eclipse project files" option anywhere when I include. On the link you send me I do step 1 and then I am immediately forwarded to step 4. Do you know if link is build in in newer versions of android studio?

Comment: I assumed, that linking was supported in Android Studio. But even if it isn't, you can still use the same project in both IDEs. You will need to set up the settings separately, but any file changes will be synced between both IDEs automatically (because they access the same files).

Comment: Even if the 2 projects are in the same folder, they are not linked to each other. That means that every time I add a new file to Android studio I have to add it to the Eclipse as well...

Comment: If you create a file `C:\project\test.txt` in Android Studio, you won't even be able to create the same file using Eclipse, because it already exists. If you refresh Eclipse, it _will_ show the created file. As long as both project point to the exact same project path, they are linked by default. You can even create a file outside any IDE, and it will show up in both IDEs. If it doesn't, your projects are not pointing to the same directory.

Comment: Yes you are right. When I refreshed the Eclipse project all changes were applied. What I was doing all this time is reopening the Eclipse because I assumed Eclipse auto-refresh open projects on loading. I guess I was wrong. Thanks for your help, I am accepting your answer.